# Connect a Hololens to internet without wifi, over USB?

Tags: networking, hololens

Is there any other way to connect a Hololens to internet other than Wifi? For instance, over the usb connection to another computer that is connected by a physical ethernet cable? I'm wanting the internet connection for streaming data from the internet when launching an app. Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reaching out to the Hololens support team through Microsoft, and their response was that the Hololens does not support USB tethering or Bluetooth connections for internet. The only means of connecting is over Wi-Fi.